# How can I add a default value in a xml document under root Element using java ..?

Tags: java, xml

How can we add a default value into a tag under root element using java.Also  how can we add the timestamp in the xml using java

Comment: Hi, can you please ask a more specific question? Do you use any framework to deal with xml document? which one? what do you mean by "default value", e.g. a value when unmarshalling then document and a tag is null? Where you want to add a timestamp? What is your problem with adding a timestamp?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - did you create a XSD for your XML?

Comment: Here You should get all You need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984323/how-to-add-an-element-in-this-xml-file-using-dom-parser

Comment: Apologies Everyone for not providing detailed information on this query...Will make a note of this going ahead...Thanks Piotr 'Kowcio' Kowalski for providing the reference...